# ImportError: No module named 'django_select2'

Tags: django, pythonanywhere

I am trying to deploy my django application on the `pythonanywhere`. I have install all the packages that requires for the application. I am also using `django_select2` reusable app in my application.

Firstly, i activate virtual environment and install the `django_select2` by this command :

```
$ pip install django_select2
```

When i execute below command

```
$ pip freeze 
cryptography==2.2.2                                                                                                                                                                                               
Django==2.0.7                                                                                                                                                                                                     
django-appconf==1.0.2                                                                                                                                                                                             
django-select2==6.1.0                                                                                                                                                                                             
Flask==1.0.2                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Flask-JWT==0.3.2                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2                                                                                                                                                                                           
furl==1.2                                                                                                                                                                                                         
idna==2.7
```

As you see `django_select2` is also in the installed list. I also check `site-packages` inside my virual environment. There is also `django_select2` folder.

However when i run my app it generates the `ImportError: No module named 'django_select2'` inside my `error.log`

Here is the part of my `error.log`

```
2018-07-14 14:18:53,934: Error running WSGI application
2018-07-14 14:18:53,934: ImportError: No module named 'django_select2'
2018-07-14 14:18:53,934:   File "/var/www/harunergul_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 22, in <module>
2018-07-14 14:18:53,935:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2018-07-14 14:18:53,935: 
2018-07-14 14:18:53,935:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
2018-07-14 14:18:53,935:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2018-07-14 14:18:53,935: 
2018-07-14 14:18:53,935:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
2018-07-14 14:18:53,935:     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
2018-07-14 14:18:53,935: 
2018-07-14 14:18:53,935:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
2018-07-14 14:18:53,936:     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
2018-07-14 14:18:53,936: 
2018-07-14 14:18:53,936:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
2018-07-14 14:18:53,936:     module = import_module(entry)
```

Any suggestions? What i have missing?

Comment: According to the docs:
Add django_select2 to your INSTALLED_APPS in your project settings.
Add django_select to your urlconf if you use any "Auto" fields.
url(r'^select2/', include('django_select2.urls')),  Also are you managing your project in a virtual env? it confusing to see both Django and Flask both in the same project.

Comment: Actually i don't have any flask project. There are just flask files in the virtualenv. I think i figure out the problem. I will give the details as a answer. Thank you for your attention @ChuckLaPress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is application is not using virtual environment in this case. If we look at the below line we will see `/usr/local/...` .  So the application is using `pythonanywhere.com` default environment.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13,
```

which means whatever we install in our `virtualenv` has no effect on default server. In `pythonanywhere.com` there is virtualenv menu, be sure if you input correct path info in this menu.

Answer (score 2):

The default pip on PythonAnywhere is for Python 2.7, so you've been installing your modules into the wrong version of Python (your web app is using 3.5). Use pip3.5 to install your modules.